# IIS server error .Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8

[image]

This is an ASP.NET MVC app but using the Web Forms View Engine (.aspx) instead of the Razor View Engine (.cshtml).

I've set the default start page to Login.aspx in the project and in IIS default document. However if i enter http://localhost:150/Login.aspx to the web browser it works.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do the config RouteConfig file says that default controller and actions are Home, Index?

Comment: @AlejandroPérezFals Hi this is my first time dealing with publishing mvc app . I just checked  the route config and this is what i see             
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }

Comment: your route '/' says that the controller and the action you are trying to access is Home, Index. Make sure you have a Home controller and an Index action.

Comment: What do you mean "but with aspx webform pages instead of views"? Do you mean that you actually have views, but they are using the Web Forms View Engine instead of the Razor View Engine?

Comment: @mason correct webforms aspx instead of cshtml

Comment: @AlejandroPérezFals I have looked at documentation for a homecontroller. I have created one but what should i put into the index action? right now it shows "return View()" which I do not have a view.

Comment: @AlejandroPérezFalsI just want to set it to login.aspx. do I need to modify the route config file?I do not have an index file.

Comment: You can't mix and match Web Forms and MVC in that way. Both can be used in the same project, but if you've got .aspx pages, you're using Web Forms there, not MVC.

Comment: @ChrisPratt You can use .aspx for the views instead of .cshtml. It's called the Web Forms View Engine. Not that I recommend it, but [it exists](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/differences-between-razor-and-aspx-view-engine-in-mvc/). Having .aspx doesn't necessarily mean you're using Web Forms.

Comment: @mason: You can use them as *views* to return from actions, but you can't use them directly, i.e. navigating to `Login.aspx` literally in your address bar. If you're doing that, you're using Web Forms. Period.

Comment: @ChrisPtratt True, just I took what you originally said to mean that .aspx always means you're using Web Forms.

Comment: @AlejandroPérezFals . I have figured it out and posted the answer. Thank you for trying to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I moved my login page into the VIEWS folder ( it wasn't before).

Created a default controller

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Default
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
        }
    }
```

And not everything seems to work.  Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access to the route '/' you should have a HomeController. Inside this controller, put an Index action that returns View(). Then create a Index.aspx file in the Views/Home folder. If you want access to other view when you enter to your site with route '/', then you should change your RouteConfig file, and set the default controller and action to others.